trying to understand why Java 21 with ZGC is not trying to get memory below SoftMaxHeap
we have a Java Application running with Java 21 Version 21+35-LTS. ZGC is enabled. From my POV Java is behaving strangely and i am trying to understand why. The Application is configured as follows:
-X38000
-x38000
--javaarg -XX:+UseZGC
--javaarg -XX:+ZGenerational
--javaarg -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
--javaarg -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=20
--javaarg -XX:-ZUncommit
--javaarg -XX:SoftMaxHeapSize=24000M
--javaarg -Xlog:async
--javaarg -Xlog:gc*,gc+reloc=warning,gc+marking=warning,gc+phases=warning,gc+mmu=warning,gc+metaspace=warning,gc+nmethod=warning,gc+load=warning,gc+task=warning:/log/app_gc_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log:time,uptime,level,tags,tid:filecount=0

We had good results with those settings so far and during tests.
But what i now see is strange to me. While connected via VisualVM to JMX is see that the App is using ~30 something GB of memory.
No CPU load, no higher GC activity. Since SoftMaxHeap is configured to be 24GB i would expect that Java at least tries to get the memory below this mark, but it does not.
If i then perform a manual GC via VisualVM it does exactly what i would expect it to do. CPU activity goes up, GC activity goes up, the memory gets cleared up and memory usage wents below the 24GB mark.
Please also see this screenshot.

Just to be clear. We dont have any problems, i am just wondering why Java behaves like this.
I dont unterstand why Java is not trying to get it below the 24GB mark without me intervening. I would expect Java to always try getting the memory below the SoftMaxHeap.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
